# How can I fix this logic sentence error without exceptions?

Tags: java, logic

**Introduction**

The code I am going to present now is part of a loop for a game. I am having problems with a error handling **(not through exceptions)**.

**Problem**

This next function takes 4 int variables `(row_1, col_1, row_2, col_2)` which have to be checked if they are less than `(size-1)`.

The reason behind is that we are working with a matrix and the range is `from 0 to (size-1)`.

So if the user inputs less than 0 or more than (size-1) it should be asking again for an input

**Code**

```
 public static void gameLoop()
{
    //While you still play (true) or if (false) -> end game
    showMatrix(gameMatrix);//Cheat
    while(play == true)
        {
            showMatrix(displayMatrix);
            System.out.println("--------------------");
            System.out.println("Input first row and col press enter between inputs");
            System.out.print("First row: ");
                row_1 = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("First column: ");
                col_1 = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Input second row and col press enter between inputs");
            System.out.print("Second row: ");
                row_2 = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Second column: ");
                col_2 = scan.nextInt();

                if (row_1 == row_2 && col_1 == col_2)
                {
                    System.out.println("I tested this!");
                    showMatrix(displayMatrix);
                    System.out.println("--------------------");
                    System.out.println("[ERROR] Input not valid! Try again");
                    System.out.println("Input first row and col press enter between inputs");
                    System.out.print("First row: ");
                        row_1 = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("First column: ");
                        col_1 = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Input second row and col press enter between inputs");
                    System.out.print("Second row: ");
                        row_2 = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Second column: ");
                        col_2 = scan.nextInt();
                }
                else if ((row_1 > size || row_1 < 0) && (row_2 > size || row_2 < 0) && (col_1 > size || col_2 < 0) && ((col_2 > size || col_2 < 0)))     
                {
                    System.out.println("I tested that!");
                    showMatrix(displayMatrix);
                    System.out.println("--------------------");
                    System.out.println("[ERROR] Input not valid! Try again");
                    System.out.println("Input first row and col press enter between inputs");
                    System.out.print("First row: ");
                        row_1 = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("First column: ");
                        col_1 = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Input second row and col press enter between inputs");
                    System.out.print("Second row: ");
                        row_2 = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Second column: ");
                        col_2 = scan.nextInt();
                }


            Turn(row_1, col_1, row_2, col_2, gameMatrix);
            check = checkEndgame(gameMatrix, displayMatrix);

                if(check == false)
                {
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y/N");
                        game_option = scan.next();

                        if ("Y".equals(game_option) || "y".equals(game_option))
                        {
                            createGame();
                            gameLoop();
                        }     
                        else if ("N".equals(game_option) || "n".equals(game_option))
                        {
                            play = false;
                        }
                }


        }
}
```

**Part of the code with the problem**

```
if (row_1 == row_2 && col_1 == col_2){}

else if ((row_1 > size || row_1 < 0) && (row_2 > size || row_2 < 0) && (col_1 > size || col_2 < 0) && ((col_2 > size || col_2 < 0))){}
```

**Question**

I do not understand where I did go wrong with this logic after testing numbers which should trigger it.

**Notes**

- Feel free to judge the code and help me with design or error handling
- Those `System.out.println("I tested that!"); && System.out.println("I tested this!");` are debug stdout.

Comment: I'm just commenting the last line you posted: Shouldn't it be `row_1 >= (size - 1)` and so on since you want it to not be more than (size - 1) ? Also, all these conditions have to happen at the same time as you wrote it, maybe you are looking for `||`s instead of `&&`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Suggestions:**

Console applications are unforgiving and unless handled carefully at the development stage can lead to an application no one wants to use because of its inability to handle input Errors or simple typing mistakes. How many times are you willing to restart an application.

People do make entry mistakes and the more informative your application is the less mistakes a User will make. For example, if you only want Users to input a value from 0 to let's say 10 then let them know what the requirements are, constantly:

```
Please enter the numerical values for FIRST Row and Column:
First Row (0 to 10): 7
First Column (0 to 10): |
```

You will always need to validate input so as to ensure that what is provided will actually process without any errors being generated. As you well know the keyboard is a pretty big input device with an awful lot of buttons on it and any one of then can be accidentally struck during input without the User even being aware of it. After all, everyone that owns a keyboard is **automatically** a typing master and can pump out 400 words per minute without looking at the screen. Well....so it seems and to be quite honest, I'm am by no means any exception to that.

Allow the User to carry out a re-entry should an error occur. Don't be afraid to utilize **while** loops for this, even nested ones. If handled correctly, there will be no issues with them.

Although this portion of your application is small, allow the User to quit at any time unless of course the current point ***needs*** to be completed in order to accomplish a clean exit. It's nasty when you can't get out of an application unless you finish it. especially when you just don't want to.

Where you can, use Methods or Classes to reduce or eliminate code duplication. Sometimes it is easier to read code when its long and drawn out with lots of duplication but in most cases it doesn't take long to get sick of looking at it. It can make you dizzy after a while. The old excuse "I just do it to get it working then I clean it up" really doesn't fly, well for the most part. If you can eliminate code duplication right away that way you don't have to code your application twice...or three times...or maybe more. Yes, we all do it in one form or another and again, I'm no exception to this.

By removing most code duplication and adding a small method or two your particular code segment might look something like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      // Declare Scanner (here for sake of this demo)
String LS = System.lineSeparator();         // System line Separator. 
boolean play = true;                        // Play flag
int size = 8;                               // 8 is used for sake of this demo
String range = "(0 to " + (size - 1) + ")"; // Range so we don't have to keep typing it.
String[] rowCol;                            // Array to hold Row and Column string numerical values
String border1 = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(72, "-")); // Text Border 1 (-)
String border2 = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(42, "=")); // Text Border 2 (=)

while (play) {
    String input = "";  // Input from scanner goes in this variable
    rowCol = new String[4]; // Initialize Array
    // Declare & init int variables to hold input integer values (if desired)
    // Un-comment the below line if you want this...
    // int row_1 = -1, col_1 = -1, row_2 = -1, col_2 = -1; 

    // Inform of what is required...
    System.out.println(border1);
    System.out.println("Please enter the numerical values for FIRST and "
            + "SECOND Rows and Columns." + LS + "Follow the provided prompts. "
            + "You can Enter 'q' or 'quit' at any time to" + LS + "end the game.");
    System.out.println(border1);

    // Get Input from User
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCol.length; i++) {
        // Set up current prompt...
        String prompt = LS;
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                prompt += "Enter First Row Value " + range + ": ";
                break;
            case 1:
                prompt += "Enter First Column Value " + range + ": ";
                break;
            case 2:
                prompt += "Enter Secomd Row Value " + range + ": ";
                break;
            case 3:
                prompt += "Enter Second Column Value " + range + ": ";
                break;
        }

        input = "";     // Clear input variable
        // Get the actual input from User and validate.
        while (input.equals("")) {
            System.out.print(prompt);       // Display prompt
            input = scan.nextLine();        // Get keyboard input from User

            // Validate input...
            if (!validateUserRowColInput(0, (size - 1), input)) {
                input = ""; // Input was invalid so clear input variable
                continue;   // Re-prompt the User for proper input
            }
            rowCol[i] = input;  // All is good so add input to Array element at index i.
        }
    }

    // Display what was provided.
    System.out.println(border2);
    System.out.println("Row 1/Column 1  = " + rowCol[0] + "/" + rowCol[1] + LS
            + "Row 2/Column 2  = " + rowCol[2] + "/" + rowCol[3]);
    System.out.println(border2 + LS);
}
```

The rest of your game loop code you can add yourself. In the above code a simple String Array (named **rowCol**) is utilized to hold the values supplied by a User. This allows us to use a single **for** loop nested within the main play **while** loop to prompt for all 4 inputs from the User therefore eliminating some duplicate code and carrying out input validation all in one house so to speak.

If you want to convert the inputs to Integer (int's) then you could do something like this instead (directly after the **for** loop):

```
/* Array index 0 and 1 now contains the string numerical 
   values for First Row and First Column. Array index 2 and
   3 now contains the string numerical values for Second Row 
   and Second Column. If you just can't wrap your head around 
   dealing with Arrays and indexes from this point then do 
   something like the following:     */

// Convert String Array elements to integers
row_1 = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[0]);
col_1 = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[1]);
row_2 = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[2]);
col_2 = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[3]);

// Display what was provided.
System.out.println(border2);
System.out.println("Row 1/Column 1  = " + row_1 + "/" + col_1 + LS
        + "Row 2/Column 2  = " + row_2 + "/" + col_2);
System.out.println(border2 + LS);
```

The **validateUserRowColInput()** method which as it implies, validates the Users input to respect the desired rules for the code segment above. It is called directly after the User supplies input. The validation rules are basically what you had laid out within your post and the validation is done upon each input supplied rather than waiting for all four inputs to be provided:

**Validation Rules:**

- No Blank entries allowed;
- Only numerical characters can be supplied, no alpha characters other
  than **q** or the word **quit** are accepted (not case sensitive);
- If **q** or the word **quit** is supplied the program ends;
- Row 1 and or Row 2 can not be Less Than 0;
- Column 1 and or Column 2 can not be less than 0;
- Row 1 and or Row 2 can not be Greater Than (size - 1);
- Column 1 and or Column 2 can not be Greater than (size - 1);

The User is of course informed if a rule is broken and given the opportunity to make a correct entry. Here is the **validateUserRowColInput()** method:

```
/**
 * Validates the User's Row and Column values input. This method checks to
 * ensure only numerical characters were entered. It also ensures the the
 * numerical value entered is between and or equal to the supplied minValue
 * and maxValue.
 *
 * @param minVal      (Integer) The minium Allowable integer value to be
 *                    entered.
 * @param maxVal      (Integer) The maximum allowable integer value to be
 *                    entered.
 * @param inputString (String) String representation of the integer value
 *                    supplied.
 *
 * @return (Boolean) True if the entry is valid and false if it is not.
 */
private static boolean validateUserRowColInput(int minVal, int maxVal, String inputString) {
    String LS = System.lineSeparator();
    if (inputString.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry! You must supply a numerical "
                + "value from " + minVal + " to " + maxVal + ".");
        return false;
    }
    if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("q") || inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        System.out.println("We hope you had fun. Bye Bye");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (!inputString.matches("\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input supplied (" + inputString + ")! "
                + "You can not supply alpha characters, only" + LS 
                + "numerical values are allowed!. Please try again...");
        return false;
    }
    int num = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
    if (num < minVal || num > maxVal) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input supplied (" + inputString + ")! "
                + "The numerical value you supply can not be" + LS + "less "
                + "than " + minVal + " and no greater than " + maxVal + ". "
                + "Please try again...");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Yes....this can all be reduced even more.

Comment: This answer is a masterpiece! Well detailed and comprehensive. Thanks a lot this is going to help me in future code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `do...while` loop to make sure the inputs are valid. It takes a `boolean` argument:

```
do {
    // All the System.out.println and Scanner stuff...
} while(!checkAnswers(row_1, row_2, col_1, col_2));
```

Now we have to write the function checkAnswers that will return the boolean to state whether the user is allowed to quit the `do...while` loop:

```
public static boolean checkAnswers(int row_1, int row_2, int col_1, int col_2) {
    // I don't know why you needed that condition, but I let it there
    if(row_1 == row_2 || col_1 == col_2) return false; 

    // check if the rows and colls are in the range 0...(size - 1)
    int[] rowsAndCols = {row_1, row_2, col_1, col_2};
    for(int i : rowsAndCols)
        if(i < 0 || i >= (size - 1)) return false;

    // If everything is good we can quit the do...while loop
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!